# Unificar varias listas en una sola

Tags: python, lista

Tengo en Python una lista como esta:

```
['CM', 'CM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM, CAM', 'CM, CAM', 'CM, CAM']
```

Que, si os fijáis, en alguno de los casos los valores se guardan como: `'CM, LM'` por lo que un elemento puede ser: `'CM'` o `'CM, LM'`.

De esa lista, necesito obtener la siguiente:

```
{'CM', 'LM', 'CAM'}
```

Es decir, eliminar los duplicados con un `set()`. Pero antes, necesito separar las cadenas para evitar que haya algo como esto: `'CM, LM'`.

He intentado hacerlo asi:

```
new_list = [x.split(", ") for x in player_dict[key][column]]
```

Pero me devuelve esto:

```
[['CM'], ['CM'], ['CM', 'LM'], ['CM', 'LM'], ['CM', 'LM', 'CAM'], ['CM', 'CAM'], ['CM', 'CAM']]
```

**¿Como puedo eliminar las listas dentro de la lista, y unificarlo todo en una única lista, para poder eliminar los duplicados?**

Comment: Desempaqueta luego de hacer `split` usando `*`.

Comment: ¿Como? No te he entendido, disculpa

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya intenté eso y no funcionó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Optimización usando set comprehensions:

```py
lista = ['CM', 'CM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM, CAM', 'CM, CAM', 'CM, CAM']

new_lista = {y for x in lista for y in x.split(", ")}

print(new_lista)
```

---

## Optimización:

```py
lista = ['CM', 'CM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM, CAM', 'CM, CAM', 'CM, CAM']

new_lista = set()
for sublista in lista:
    for elemento in sublista.split(", "):
        if not elemento in new_lista:
            new_lista.add(elemento)

print(new_lista)
```

---

Puedes recorrer el resultado de cada `split` y usar `extend` en una lista nueva de la siguiente manera:

```py
lista = ['CM', 'CM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM', 'CM, LM, CAM', 'CM, CAM', 'CM, CAM']

new_lista = []
for lista_separada in [x.split(", ") for x in lista]:
    new_lista.extend(lista_separada)

new_lista = set(new_lista)
print(new_lista)
```

Comment: Si alguien conoce una solución más "pythonica" bienvenido sea

Comment: Yo creo que puedes recorrer la lista directamente y recién dentro del for hacer el split.

Comment: Sí, creo que eso optimizaría el uso de memoria, no? Porque así no tiene que guardar todos los resultados de los split al mismo tiempo. También podría saltearme el paso de `set()` si evito agregar elementos repetidos en primer lugar. Ya lo hago

Comment: @DanteS. Ya edité la respuesta, creo que el nuevo código es óptimo

Comment: Ahora que me acuerdo, definitivamente los más optimo es usando `Set Comprehensions`. En una sola línea queda todo `new_lista = {y for x in lista for y in x.split(", ")}`. Agréga esta vía a tu respuesta por favor. Puedes probarlo [acá](https://www.online-python.com/qhoWLyfa8N).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Listo! Me vuelve loco lo de las list comprehensions anidadas. Aún no logro entender por qué el loop interno va a la derecha.

Comment: @FedericoMeza a mi antes me volvían loco también, hasta que aprendí a mirarlas como si fueran `for` anidados sencillos. Si lo miras bien, y haces un enter imaginario al inicio del segundo `for`. Basicamente no es más que un `for` dentro de otro `for` de toda la vida, justo en el orden en que los declararías sin `list comprehensions`. Buena respuesta y muy completa, ya tienes mi voto.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Gracias, también lo vi en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/8891434). Yo solo había usado las de la forma `[[x for x in y] for y in z]` pero esta forma está muy interesante.